# How to insert an image with the ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I need to modify my code to make it show the text with image not to change the whole code to another one with image function:

This is my code for images:

```
 int[] imgs = new int[]
    {
        R.drawable.wifi,
        R.drawable.bluetooth,
        R.drawable.usb,
        R.drawable.cloud,
        R.drawable.remote,

    };
```

And this is my ListView code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.operations);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
String[] values = new String[]
        {"Nearby Wifi",
         "Nearby Blutooth",
         "Direct USB Connected",
         "Google Cloud Print",
         "Printer Remote"
        };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.custom_listview, android.R.id.text1, values);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {


        int itemPosition = position;

        String itemValue = (String)   listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        //if condition
    }


});
```

And this is my `custom_listview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="3dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textStyle="bold"
  />
```

How to modify it to show the text with the image?

Comment: Post your `custom_listview` layout file...

Comment: i edited my question , see it

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize listview, for that you need

1. Custom listview row xml (Imageview & Textview)
2. Custom base adapter

Follow this link,
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9

Answer (score 0):

The view that come back on your adapter is a TextView. What you can do is use 
[setCompoundDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Example:
    Edit:
    ...

```
    listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return values.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_textview);

                TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                tv.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(imgs[position]), null, null, null);
tv.setText(values.get(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    });
```

Comment: android can't resolve :context and setCompoundDrawables

Comment: The context is whatever your context is... if you are inside an activity you don't need to do put context, if you are in a fragment use getActivity(), etc...

For the setCompoundDrawables you need to cast it to a (TextView)... I have edited my answer with the code.

Comment: excuse me , i'm newly on android , and i shown  all the activity in my question, and this is layout

Comment: can't resolve "context", so i have to replace it with what ?!

Comment: I edited my answer with a copy and paste solution. I also recomend you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android